# How to dismiss a popover view in iOS9 by UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, popover

Currently I am trying to dismiss a popover view controller by the click of a `UIBarButtonItem`. The new iOS has deprecated the old way of doing this and I cannot find anything on how to do it with iOS 9. I have currently added the popover through segues.

```
- (IBAction)backButtonAction:(id)sender {
    buttonCount++;
    if (buttonCount == 1 ) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    buttonCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: show your code Please, If you don't mind.

Comment: - (IBAction)backButtonAction:(id)sender {
    buttonCount++;
    if (buttonCount == 1 ) {
        
    
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

      }
    
    buttonCount = 0;
}

Comment: This is my code that I put in my view that is acting as the popover

Comment: @Lozo Add the relevant code in your post by editing it. Don't post it as comment. It is barely readable as comment

Comment: I apologize, thank you for clarifying

Comment: Any specific reason why you are using a global variable named `buttonCount`? Does the code even get into the condition block checking if it is 1?

Comment: thank you, you are a wizard

Answer (score 0):

`UIPopoverController` has a magic function `dismissPopoverAnimated:`, you call it to dismiss the popover. Good Luck!